# Uso de contactos en Login Activity de Android Studio

Tags: android

Mi versión de Android Studio es la última que hay ahora mismo. Estoy tratando de usar la plantilla de LoginActivity. Al cargar, tal cual viene, pide aceptar permisos para usar contactos y después en el código hace uso de LoaderCallbacks como  interfaz.

Alguien podría explicarme, entiendo que no pormenorizadamente, pero si a rasgos generales la funcionalidad que aporta los elementos anteriores mencionados y métodos como mayRequestContacts o onCreateLoader o onLoadFinished...

Yo para que lo quiero es para un login contra una base de datos MySQL que sé donde tengo que añadir el código pero el resto de cosas mencionadas escapa de mi conocimientos.

Gracias de antemano.

Un saludo

Comment: Estaría bueno que pongas cual es el código actual de tu LoginActivity, para que otros puedan ayudarte más facilmente.